# npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ngx-pagination failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

Tags: npm-install

While installing any npm package, I am getting the same error every time.

Tried to remove and set proxy but it didn't work.

tabish@appventurez:~/Documents/projects/InstaCEI/InstaCEI_Website$ sudo npm i ngx-pagination --save
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ngx-pagination failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tabish/.npm/_logs/2019-06-19T11_27_35_023Z-debug.log

tabish@appventurez:~/Documents/projects/InstaCEI/InstaCEI_Website$ sudo npm i ngx-pagination --save
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ngx-pagination failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tabish/.npm/_logs/2019-06-19T11_27_35_023Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

One reason is about your IP address setup.
Check `ip addr`, `ping`, and `netplan` if ubuntu.

In my example, I setup a static IP of an ubuntu (18.04) VM, but I forgot the DNS. 
Then I got the exactly same error as you.

I fix this problem by changing the file `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` as below:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
         ens33:
                 addresses: [192.168.233.132/24]
                 dhcp4: no
                 gateway4: 192.168.233.2
                 optional: true
                 nameservers:
                         addresses: [223.5.5.5, 8.8.8.8]
    version: 2
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 natively and I have no problem pinging/curling https://registry.npmjs.org and I can even download the package that returns this error but still npm install fails, was it the same for you?